# Ionic React - Something is already running on port 8100

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, ionic-framework

So I get the above error when running `ionic serve` and my express server is already running on that port. However I need them to be both running on that port as if not, my front end wont connect to the api's endpoints.

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: It doesn't work this way. Either you run them on separate ports and change your code in such a way that the frontend calls the API on the other port with CORS, or you change the backend code so that it also serves the frontend files for you, or you run a reverse proxy which aggregates both services and directs the traffic to the right one based on the URL path.

Comment: Thanks for the info, for now I will go with the first route, just have to learn about cors now

Comment: https://medium.com/zero-equals-false/using-cors-in-express-cac7e29b005b - Express has an easy CORS middleware which you can use, that should solve your problem

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful